# Add folders to 'libraries'

Tags: dual-boot, directory, libraries

I am dual-booting windows 8 and Ubuntu 12.10. Now I have all my documents and media files in the windows partition/windows library. In windows, for example, in the documents library we can add a folder from other directories so we can view all those in one single place. So how can I view all those folders in windows partition under Ubuntu libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should mount your Windows partition under Ubuntu in order to view your Windows libraries: http://www.hecticgeek.com/2012/10/make-ntfs-partitions-read-only-in-ubuntu/

Additionally, you could read how to harmonize your dual-boot setup for Windows and Ubuntu here: 
http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/35807/how-to-harmonize-your-dual-boot-setup-for-windows-and-ubuntu/